# Type 深圳 in Japanese in PC/MacOS

Tags: discussion, kanji

I want to type 深圳(しんせん) in Japanese.

In Windows (win7) and MacOS (10.15), when I type しんせん, there's no option for 深圳.

[image: Options in Win7 for しんせん]

While in iOS (iOS13), there exists the option 深圳.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer like: How to add it to the IME dictionary. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027029/windows-advanced-input-methods-for-east-asian-languages
or alternate readings that could bring up those characters? Rewording the question to the later may actually make it on-topic. (not sure though)

Comment: I assume that you mean the Japanese name for Shenzhen [if not, please ignore this comment] so my first guess was to google something like  "しょんせん、中国のシリコンバレー" and copy-paste the kanji from the results, but it actually seems [big surprise to me!] that the sen is normally written in katakana (!!!!)　You can still find also the kanji version.

Answer (score 1):

macOS's system Japanese keyboard (tested on 10.15) should have [深圳]{しんせん} as a conversion, although you do have to do some digging.

[image: macOS 10.15, system Japanese keyboard conversion menu]

If you want to type words that are in Chinese but using the Japanese keyboard, only select few are available in the top conversion results. If the kanji conversion does not work, I doubt that there are better ways of doing it other than looking it up in Google or using Google Translate for this.